# Is every complex number an eigenvalue of some product of three positive definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that $A,B$ and $C$ are symmetric positive definite matrices. I guess that the eigenvalues of the matrix $D=ABC$ can be any complex numbers. Is that true?

Comment: Obviously this is false in the scalar case. Also, when the sizes of $D$ is odd, it must have at least one real eigenvalue and hence the vector of spectrum cannot be any arbitrary point in $\mathbb C^3$. If you are asking whether every complex number $z$ is realisable as an eigenvalue of some $D$, you should edit your question.

Comment: I mentioned that the eigenvalues of ... can be .... Of course, some of them can be real.

Comment: Assuming that my interpretation of the question is correct, then yes, product of three SPD matrices can have positive, negative, and even complex eigenvalues. Try some random examples.

Comment: I've edited the question title. Please feel free to roll back if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every *nonzero* complex number is an eigenvalue of the product of some three positive definite matrices. Let $x>0$ and
$$
ABC=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&x}\pmatrix{5&-2\\ -2&1}\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1}
=\pmatrix{8&3\\ -3x&-x}.
$$
Denote the two eigenvalues of $ABC$ by $\lambda_1(x)$ and $\lambda_2(x)$, where
$$
\lambda_1(x)=\frac12\left(8-x+\sqrt{(x-4)(x-16)}\right).
$$
(We take $\sqrt{y}=i\sqrt{|y|}$ when $y$ is negative.) Note that $\lambda_1(4)$ is real positive and $\lambda_1(16)$ is real negative. Also, when $4<x<16$, the imaginary part of $\lambda_1(x)$ is strictly positive. Since the path of $\lambda_1$ is continuous, it follows that every $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ is the argument of some $\lambda_1(x)$. Similarly, every $\theta\in[-\pi,0]$ is the argument of some $\lambda_2(x)$. Therefore, by scaling $A$ (or $B,C$) appropriately, we conclude that every nonzero complex number is an eigenvalue of the product of some three positive definite matrices.